# 3D scene graph for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graph

Is there any scene graph implementation for Windows Forms in .NET? It doesn't need to be free, but it can't be WPF.

I have to create a part of a bridge and color the stress accordingly. Interactive rotation would be nice, as well as zoom. I think DirectX or OpenGL would be fine.

A custom solution via XNA seems too complicated. I rather want to use a library, which provides higher level objects - optimally a scene graph, minimally triangles and light.

Comment: If the problem with WPF is that you're trying to integrate with an existing WinForms app, you should know about the `ElementHost` control that allows you to put WPF content within a Forms window.

Comment: @HenryJackson Its more a compatibility concern: mono does not support WPF ASAIK. But thanks for the hint! Didn't know that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ILNumerics provides a scene graph in 3D. And supports Windows.Forms. Here are [some examples](http://ilnumerics.net/%24VisualExamples.html).

Edit: It for sure is free: GPL version 3

Comment: Thanks! I have been testing it for two days now. Seems exactly what I was looking for. This is much faster than Matlab! If no other suggestions arrive here, this will be my favorite answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do XNA rendering within Windows Forms it seems:

http://www.google.com/search?q=xna+windows+forms

Answer (score 2):

There's SlimDX which wraps DirectX for .Net.  I've gotten samples to work, but I'm new to 3D programming and there isn't much documentation on how to use SlimDX beyond the simplistic tutorials.

Unity3D is a game engine which might meet your needs with a straight-forward installation and 3D modeling import and view.  No step-through debugger though, if that matters.

XNA might be a good choice, but I switched to evaluate SlimDX because of some concerning limitations Microsofts forces in networking gamer-services I saw early on.  It made me think there would be other limitations that I wouldn't be able to bypass.  Also, I was interested in more flexibility in performance and higher-quality realtime effects than I believed that XNA can provide.  I'd be interested in others thoughts on whether such fears about XNA are founded.  Perhaps they're not an issue for your stress visualization project.

Comment: SlimDX and XNA does not contain anything like scenegraphs. They are just multi-media API's on top of DirectX. Unity3D on the other hand, seems to support much more than simply rendering polygons on the screen.